# Problem with TIMES_CONTACTED value in android contacts data

Tags: android, contacts

I am writing an android activity that displays information about contacts (contact name, last time contacted, etc.) I am trying to show the number of times a contact is contacted using the ContactsContract.Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED column but I always get a 0 value for all contacts. I am using a Samsung galaxy S device and I saw somewhere else on the Internet that this is a problem specific to some devices (including Samsung GS). Is there another way to get this information?

Thanks

Comment: I have this problem as well with my Samsung Infuse 4G

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like Samsung does not update this value and I have not found a solution to this problem yet. It works ok on other devices though so it is definitely a Samsung problem which might be solved in future updates.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using this field to sort contacts in my app - but it doesn't work on SS Galaxy Y ( it works on Htc sensation/arc s/xperia ray). As far as I read from some forum - what we can do is: add our own ContentObserver to observer incoming/outgoing sms/calls - bad :(

Comment: Hi, did you publish your app? If you did, can you provide a link? I'd like to see it.