# How TIMES_CONTACTED works on Android

Tags: android, contacts

I try an application that simply makes a list of contact with same information (name, number, last contact, etc.) order by ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TIMES_CONTACTED.

But the values are wrong, I have 481 calls to a number I never call and 0/10 calls to the number I call most frequently. Tha phone is a HTC Legend.

Are there problems with this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick look around, it seems like other users are having the same problem with both HTC and Samsung. General guesswork seems that the TIMES_CONTACTED value isn't being updated correctly.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009072/problem-with-times-contacted-value-in-android-contacts-data) other question and [this](http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2011-01/msg04505.html) outside forum post