# Get Top Contacted data in android

Tags: android, android-contacts, calllog

I am trying to get the top contacted call log details in android. Say if the person A has been contacted for 5 times, B has been contacted for 3 times and C 10 times. Now, I want to extract C and A as my top contacted persons in my phone.

Can any body explain me how to do this. I am able to get most recent call logs now.

I referred this, but no luck

[How to get contacts with which the user talks often?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288195/how-to-get-contacts-with-which-the-user-talks-often)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do something similar in a different approach. In the Contacts API, there is a field called `ContactsContract.Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED` which tells the number of times that contact has been contacted.

This approach is not related to the CallLogs API. User can clear the CallLogs, but not the times contacted.

1. Check this link for [developer notes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) on ContactsContract.Contacts.
2. Check this link for an android library that I have created which can give you this implementation.[ae-apps-library](https://github.com/midhunhk/ae-apps-library/tree/master/library/AeAppsLibrary) You would be looking for the class `ContactManager`. Once you fetch all the contacts, you need to sort based on the times contacted field to get your required list.

**Edit:** If you see the `fetchAllContacts` method in the `ContactManager` from the library, you can see how the data are read using the API. All you need to do would be to sort this list based on the timesContacted field by writing a Custom Comparator and sorting the list using that.

Comment: I understood partially, will it possible for you to show some code if you don't mind? I'm looking into it

Comment: No luck, I am not able to do:(

Comment: What were you able to try?